# How to fix ctrl+c inside a docker container

Tags: shell, docker, kill-process

If I connect to a docker container

```
$> docker exec -it my_container zsh
```

and inside it I want to kill something I started with `ctrl+c` I noticed that it takes forever to complete. I've googled around and it seems that `ctrl+c` works a bit different than you would expect. My question, how can I fix `ctrl+c` inside a container ?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The problem is that Ctrl-C sends a signal to the top-level process inside the container, but that process doesn't necessarily react as you would expect. The top-level process has ID 1 inside the container, which means that it doesn't get the default signal handlers that processes usually have. If the top-level process is a shell, then it can receive the signal through its own handler, but doesn't forward it to the command that is executed within the shell. Details are explained [here](https://engineeringblog.yelp.com/2016/01/dumb-init-an-init-for-docker.html#process-behavior-inside-docker-containers). In both cases, the docker container acts as if it simply ignores Ctrl-C.

Starting with `docker 0.6.5`, you can add `-t` to the docker run command, which will attach a `pseudo-TTY`. Then you can type `Control-C` to detach from the container without terminating it.

If you use `-t` and `-i` then Control-C will terminate the container. When using `-i` with `-t` then you have to use `Control-P Control-Q` to detach without terminating.

Test 1:

```
$ ID=$(sudo docker run -t -d ubuntu /usr/bin/top -b)
$ sudo docker attach $ID
Control-P Control-Q
$ sudo docker ps
```

The container is still listed.

Test 2:

```
$ ID=$(sudo docker run -t -i -d ubuntu /usr/bin/top -b)
$ sudo docker attach $ID
Control-C
$ sudo docker ps
```

the container is not there (it has been terminated). If you type `Control-P` `Control-Q` instead of Control-C in the 2nd example, the container would still be running.

> Wrap the program with a docker-entrypoint.sh bash script that blocks
> the container process and is able to catch ctrl-c. This bash example
> might help:
> https://rimuhosting.com/knowledgebase/linux/misc/trapping-ctrl-c-in-bash

```
#!/bin/bash

# trap ctrl-c and call ctrl_c()
trap ctrl_c INT

function ctrl_c() {
        echo "** Trapped CTRL-C"
}

for i in `seq 1 5`; do
    sleep 1
    echo -n "."
done
```

Comment: I get the impression (and please correct me if I'm wrong) that what you describe  `ctrl+c` is for exiting the container, which is not what I want. I want to stop a program I'v manually started

Comment: Please elaborate on how a script would block the container process, and what is supposed to be done in the Ctrl-C trap.

Comment: OT: I think stopping the container with CTRL+C is a bad design...I keep accidentally stopping the container simply because of a habit of exiting shell process this way.

Comment: Thanks! Now I really know why it would be a good idea to always add `-it`. By the way, it is easy to remember too. Just `docker run -it ...`! :-D

Answer (score 20):

In some cases, when I used ctrl-C to terminate a process inside a container, the container terminates.

Additionally, I've seen cases where processes running inside containers leave zombie processes.

I have found that when starting a container with the `--init` switch, both of these problems are addressed.  This appears to make my containers operate in a more "normal, expected UNIX-like manner".

Note: `--init` is different from `-i`, which is short for `--interactive`

If you want more information on what the `--init` switch does, please read up on it on the Docker web pages that include information on `docker run`.  The information on that web page says "Run an init inside the container that forwards signals and reaps processes".

Comment: The solution that really works for me.

Answer (score 18):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
it kills the process instead of politely asking it to shut down.(read more [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/14158).)

Comment: It does not work for me. When the running docker container does not respond to `Ctrl+C` then it ignore `Ctrl+\ ` too

Comment: It worked for me. I was connected (ssh) to an EC2 instance (amazon Linux) on which I ran a docker container. I used iTerm2 on a Mac.

Answer (score 9):

```
when your docker terminal is not responding to Ctrl+C/Ctrl+D/Ctrl+/, try these steps:

#1>> Open another terminal session and enter the command:

    **`docker container ls`** 
        or
    **`docker container list`**


#2>> locate the container id from the above list and issue the docker container stop command:
    

**`docker stop <<containerId>>`**

#3>> next time when you launch the docker container, use the flag "**-it**"  to respond to the Ctrl+C event
```

**docker run -it <>**

```
    Now you can stop ,with control+C
```

Comment: Easy and simple to use. Thanks

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 8):

I had the similar problem when I was trying to run `mdbook` (the Rust executable) in the docker container. The `mdbook` starts simple webserver and I want to stop it via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> which did not work.

```
$ docker -ti --rm -p 4321:4321 my-docker-image mdbook serve --hostname 0.0.0.0 --port 4321
2019-08-16 14:00:11 [INFO] (mdbook::book): Book building has started
2019-08-16 14:00:11 [INFO] (mdbook::book): Running the html backend
2019-08-16 14:00:11 [INFO] (mdbook::cmd::serve): Serving on: http://0.0.0.0:4321
2019-08-16 14:00:11 [INFO] (ws): Listening for new connections on 0.0.0.0:3001.
2019-08-16 14:00:11 [INFO] (mdbook::cmd::watch): Listening for changes...
^C^C
```

Be inspired by @NID's answer I encapsulated the mdbook executable by universal bash script `docker-entrypoint.sh` which did the trick (without the need to explicitly catch the INT signal).

```
$ docker -ti --rm -p 4321:4321 my-docker-image docker-entrypoint.sh mdbook serve --hostname 0.0.0.0 --port 4321
2019-08-16 14:00:11 [INFO] (mdbook::book): Book building has started
2019-08-16 14:00:11 [INFO] (mdbook::book): Running the html backend
2019-08-16 14:00:11 [INFO] (mdbook::cmd::serve): Serving on: http://0.0.0.0:4321
2019-08-16 14:00:11 [INFO] (ws): Listening for new connections on 0.0.0.0:3001.
2019-08-16 14:00:11 [INFO] (mdbook::cmd::watch): Listening for changes...
^C $
```

The content of the `docker-entrypoint.sh` is very simple:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

$@
```

Comment: This is nice, thnx. The only downside I see with this is that you have to write down the whole command

Comment: Open your favorite editor, write there the two lines mentioned above and save it as `docker-entrypoint.sh` :-) Then add this file to the image via `ADD` command in your Dockerfile.

Comment: I had a similar issue with mdbook and Ctrl+C, and adding `--init` worked for me. Here is my full command: `docker run --rm -t -i --init -p 6400:6400 -v ${PWD}:/book $$(docker build -q .) mdbook serve --hostname 0.0.0.0 --port 6400 /book`. The dockerfile does not include ENTRYPOINT.

Answer (score 6):

I tried the `--init` solution by @Remy Orange and it worked for me. After some searching, including i)[How to use --init parameter in docker run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43122080/how-to-use-init-parameter-in-docker-run), ii) [What is advantage of Tini?](https://github.com/krallin/tini/issues/8) and iii) [init](https://github.com/docker-library/official-images#init), I wrote the detailed solution below:

1. Install `tini` on Ubuntu:

- via launching:

```
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt install tini
```

- Or, if `tini` is not available in your distribution or is too old, please check a Dockerfile to add tini at [here](https://github.com/docker-library/official-images#init).

2. Run your Docker container with `--init`:

```
docker run -ti --init --rm YOUR_DOCKER_CONTAINER_EXMAPLE bash
```

3. Then you come into your docker container and you can run some processes or experiments. E.g., run a Python code, then you can launch `Ctrl + C` to cancel this Python code, just as what you can do on Ubuntu (i.e., the regular terminal which is outside the docker container).
4. See the screenshot in my case:

- launching `Ctrl + C (i.e., ^C)` to cancel the python process:
  [image]
- It stops, showing `KeyboardInterrupt` as expected:
  [image]

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Or you can also 1) run "docker exec -it SOME_CONTAINER_ID ps -aus" to find the SOME_PID in the container; then 2) run "docker exec -it SOME_CONTAINER_ID kill -9 SOME_PID" to kill the process inside the docker container.

Answer (score 4):

If you use *Docker Compose*, you can add the [`init`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#init) parameter to forward signals to the container:

```
version: "2.4"
services:
  web:
    image: alpine:latest
    init: true
```

To make it work you need to have the option `-ti` in your `docker exec` command.

Answer (score 3):

Wasted about 2 hours.

New commands -- (Working fine)

```
sudo docker stop 
sudo docker rm   
sudo docker run -t
```

Old commands -- (Not working anymore)

```
sudo docker stop
sudo docker rm   
sudo docker run
Ctrl + C
sudo docker start
```

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

For whom still have this issue, worked for me the `Ctrl+d`. Neither `Ctrl+c` or `Ctrl+z` worked.

Comment: Ctrl+Z works fine after docker run, thanks!

Comment: @Nigrimmist nooooo

Answer (score 2):

For me <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> works only after running a container with `docker run -it <container id/name>`

Comment: This simply doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

With the base image `node:14`, I could stop the container.

But when I tried `node:18` and `node:20` it stopped working.

I don't know what changed, but this is not convenient.

Fortunately, the workaround above helped me: press `Control+\` to stop the container.