# How to source an entry point script with Docker?

Tags: bash, docker, conda, entry-point

I have an Docker image and I can run it:

```
docker run -it --entrypoint="/bin/bash" gcr.io/docker:tag
```

Then I can source a script in the following way:

```
root@86bfac2f6ccc:/# source entrypoint.sh
```

The script looks like that:

```
more entrypoint.sh
#!/bin/bash
. /env.sh
. /root/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda activate base
exec "$@"
```

Which activate the base env:

```
(base) root@86bfac2f6ccc:/#
```

So far so good but I don't managed to include this in the `Dockerfile` or as parameters to `docker run`:

I tried many things:

For example:

```
docker run -it --entrypoint="/bin/bash"  gcr.io/docker:tag  source entrypoint.sh
/bin/bash: source: No such file or directory
```

But the script exist and can be executed:

```
docker run -it --entrypoint="/bin/ls"  gcr.io/docker:tag -la
...
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   94 Apr 26 20:36 entrypoint.sh
...
```

Or:

```
docker run -it --entrypoint="/bin/bash"  gcr.io/docker:tag  ". /entrypoint.sh"
/bin/bash: . /entrypoint.sh: No such file or directory
```

Or in the Docker file:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["source", "/entrypoint.sh"]
```

I guess the issue I have is maybe related the fact that `source` evaluate a script in the current shell.

Any guidance to achieve what I want ? It seems quite obvious but I am out of idea.

Comment: did you tried `RUN source entrypoint.sh` in docker file? use ENTRYPOINT if you need to run container as executable

Comment: The only issue is that you need to run everything inside the same RUN, othervise the "conda activate base" doesn't work. The following doesn't: "RUN . entrypoint.sh && conda activate base". but "RUN conda init bash && source /root/.bashrc && conda info -e && conda activate base" does. This is discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56510575/how-to-activate-and-switch-anaconda-environment-in-dockerfile-during-build

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When Docker launches a container, there are two parts, the “entrypoint” and the “command”.  When both are specified, the “command” part is passed as command-line arguments to the “entrypoint” part.

In particular, the script you show has a very typical pattern for an entrypoint script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# ... do some setup ...
# then run the CMD passed as command-line arguments
exec "$@"
```

If your Dockerfile names this script as its `ENTRYPOINT` then you want to pass the command you want to run as the “command” part.  If you run your shell as just

```
docker run --rm -it gcr.io/docker:tag sh
```

then `sh` will be passed to the entrypoint script, which will do the setup and then eventually run it.

(Remember that `source` is a vendor-specific extension and doesn’t exist in many shells, like the minimal BusyBox shell that Alpine base images use, but that `.` means the same thing and is in the POSIX standard.  Since a container only runs one process it also doesn’t really make sense for that one process to be “source this file”; it would set up some environment variables, and then it’s done so the container exits.  The entrypoint pattern does the setup and then runs the main container command.)

Answer (score 8):

In an interactive shell, `source` tells the shell to read the commands from the file without creating a subshell. In your case, you want the initial shell to execute the commands from a script. So all you have to do is give the script as an argument. Try the following:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "/entrypoint.sh"]
```

However, it is [not a good idea](https://blog.phusion.nl/2015/01/20/docker-and-the-pid-1-zombie-reaping-problem/) to run a shell as the initial process in a container. That screws up the signal handling. You'll notice that you cannot stop execution with Ctrl-C.
Therefore, use `CMD` instead of `ENTRYPOINT` to start the shell. The initial process with id 1 should be a minimal init process, such as [`tini`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44689700/11451509).

Comment: I have the same issue using your syntax for the ENTRYPOINT.

Comment: I gave a try with tini and I am seeing the same kind of issues. Either it complain that the scrip doesn't exist or nothing happen. I think I need to do a deep dive in CMD, ENTRYPOINT, and sub SHELL. I will try to build a very simpe image which doesn't derived from a based image. I also try to look at "docker describe" but I need to understand what I am suppose to have.

Comment: @Dr.FabienTarrade "the same issue" being that `source` is not found, because bash thinks it's supposed to execute a script of that name?