# How to run bash `source` command on docker entrypoint?

Tags: bash, docker

I'm running my image like this:

```
docker run -v $PWD:/home/project -it aos /bin/bash -c "source source_me.sh && /bin/bash"
```

I wanted the script source_me to be sourced when entering. This script has some easy functions to be called with small names. However, in this case the source is not applied, because a new bash is started after the source.

Trying just

```
docker run -v $PWD:/home/project -it aos /bin/bash -c "source source_me.sh"
```

Simply returns because it finishes execution.

How can I automatically make the source stuff sourced so the user can use the commands when he enters the docker run?

Comment: I think it's better to turn that into an ENTRYPOINT script, then this might help: [How to source an entry point script with Docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56586562/2745495)

Comment: You can get Bash to source a specified file at startup, if it's interactive, by using the `--rcfile` option.  So `/bin/bash --rcfile .../source_me.sh`.  That stops the `.bashrc` file being run, so you may want to `source` it in `source_me.sh`.  I guess it's also possible that you might need to use the `-i` option to `/bin/bash` to ensure that it it behaves fully as an interactive shell.

Comment: In the question @GinoMempin cites, note that there is a shell script towards the top of the question that is usable as the image `ENTRYPOINT`.  I don't copy that script into my answer but it's an important part of the context for this question.

Comment: @DavidMaze it runs the source script but I don't get the functions defined in the source script. It's as if it just runs but in a separate terminal. Can we reopen please?