# Execute xvfb-run as docker custom command

Tags: docker, xvfb

Is there any reason why **xvfb-run** will not be executed as docker overridden command?

Having an image from this **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y xvfb
```

Built with:

```
docker build -f Dockerfile.xvfb -t xvfb-test
```

If I execute a custom docker command with xfvb-run:

```
docker run xvfb-test bash -x /usr/bin/xvfb-run echo
```

**It gets stuck and never ends**

But, if I enter to the image `docker run --rm -it xvfb-test bash`, and execute the same command **xvfb-run echo** it finished immediately (meaning that the Xvfb server started and was able to execute the command)

This is an excerpt of xvfb-run script:

```
...
trap : USR1
(trap '' USR1; exec Xvfb ":$SERVERNUM" $XVFBARGS $LISTENTCP -auth $AUTHFILE >>"$ERRORFILE" 2>&1) &
XVFBPID=$!

wait || :
...
```

Executing with `bash -x` we can see what lines is the last that was executed:

```
+ XAUTHORITY=/tmp/xvfb-run.YwmHlq/Xauthority
+ xauth source -
+ trap : USR1
+ XVFBPID=16
+ wait
+ trap '' USR1
+ exec Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1280x1024x24 -nolisten tcp -auth /tmp/xvfb-run.YwmHlq/Xauthority
```

Comment: What kind of file is `/usr/bin/xvfb-run`?  If it's a compiled binary, or a Python script, or any of a variety of other things, then `bash xvfb-run` will fail.  I might just set the Dockerfile default command `CMD ["xvfb-run"]`.

Comment: It's a sh script... I'm gonna add some details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43122080/how-to-use-init-parameter-in-docker-run)

> The docker --init option in the run command basically sets ENTRYPOINT to tini and passes the CMD to it or whatever you specify on the commandline. Without init, CMD becomes pid 1. In this case, /bin/bash

looks like running the command withouth init parameter, running as PID 1, is not handling the signal USR1 correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Looking that the **xvfb-run** script and where it gets stucked seems that the signal **USR1** (that Xvfb process sends) never gets propagated to the **wait** statement.

A way to force signal propagation is to add the **--init** flag to docker run command.
From the [documentation](https://%20https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/), is exactly what it does.

> Run an init inside the container that forwards signals and reaps processes