# Running xvfb-run when building Docker image?

Tags: docker, xvfb

I have quickly found out the reason why `xvfb-run` is failing in my scripts: [Execute xvfb-run as docker custom command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71699108/execute-xvfb-run-as-docker-custom-command). However what if I need to run `xvfb-run` while building an image? (use case here: installing some dependencies in wine / winetricks which require a running X server).

I understand the accepted answer but what if I don't have the liberty to issues `docker run --init` ? Of course, I can work around it (run `Xvfb&` and kill it manually afterwards) but using `xvfb-run` is really nice and clean so I'd like to use that if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was, in retrospect, quite obvious: install `tini` and `RUN tini -v -- xvfb-run <parameters>` in Dockerfile.