# How do I exit a command that runs inside a Docker container?

Tags: docker

I have dockerized my Symfony build tools and so I try to run `assetic:watch`:

```
docker run -ti build-tool:latest ./bin/console assetic:watch
```

This works fine until I want to exit. Ctrl-C does nothing for me and I need to use `docker stop <containerid>` to make it stop.

Is there a way of getting the container to recognize Ctrl-C as a way of killing the currently running command?

Comment: Have you tried `docker attach <containerid>` from another terminal and then stopping the container with Ctrl-C ?

Comment: Does the main process respond to Ctrl-C as you expect? Maybe it terminates on another signal?

Comment: Also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41097652/how-to-fix-ctrlc-inside-a-docker-container).